# Handle several Tap events

Tags: ios, events, uigesturerecognizer

I have an `UIView` which has an `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to it that I use to hide the keyboard when the user taps outside the `UITextFields`. Now, I also have some labels that when tapped show an `UIPickerView`. The labels use an `UITapGestureRecognizer` as well. The problem is that the events seem to canibalise themselves.

Is it possible to execute both event handlers when tapping on my labels?

Thank you.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapForUnit = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.fridgeItemUnit action:@selector(onTap)];
[self.fridgeItemUnit addGestureRecognizer:tapForUnit];
```

The above code is for one of the labels. I have removed the code for the view because my labels would stop working, but it's exactly the same, only thing different is that it is attached to `self.view` and the function that is executed is this one:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    [self.fridgeItemName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.fridgeItemQuantity resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you use for adding the gesture recognizers and handling their events? Are both of them using the same selector to handle the events?

Comment: There are two different `UITapGestureRecognizer` instances. See my edit.

Comment: You can do this with tap recognizers... but why don't you make the labels buttons?  You can make them look identical and don't have to do anything special for a pressed state, but then you can just register a target-action callback... unless you need to differentiate between a long press or something, this might be the easiest way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I guess you're right. But just for the hell of it, why wouldn't my setup work with `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: what exactly is the error that it's causing? does the app crash or do you just get some weird behavior? If it crashes please post the crashlog

Comment: It's not that it crashes, it's that if I tap on the label it *sometimes* looks as if I only tapped the view and not both the view and the label. It's basically a race condition between the two recognizers.

Comment: To have both recognizers handle the event, that requires handling the event in multiple views (which is possible but undesirable, requires extra logic, should be an absolute last resort.  I can think of plenty of examples where I thought I needed to do that and then realized there's a better way).  Seems like your error isn't a race condition, you might just be tapping near the boundary of the label, so some are handled by the label and some are handled by the view (or is this obviously not the case?).  Make 2 methods, have the view tap trigger 1 method and the button press trigger both.

Comment: I think I was wrong in my requirement for both recognizers handling the event given that they are attached to distinct views.  See @axte's answer/example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement the following method from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

I attach an example:

[image: Screenshot]

The only thing I did on the XIB was to enabled the user interaction. An here is the `.m` of the `UIViewController`:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    _viewRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTap:)];
    [_viewRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    _labelRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap:)];
    [_labelRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_viewRecognizer];
    [self.label addGestureRecognizer:_labelRecognizer];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];
    [_viewRecognizer release]; _viewRecognizer = nil;
    [_labelRecognizer release]; _labelRecognizer = nil;
    self.label = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_viewRecognizer release];
    [_labelRecognizer release];
    self.label = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)labelTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"labelTap");
}

- (void)viewTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    NSLog(@"viewTap");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer");
    return YES;
}
```

Then when tapping on the label I get the following log:

```
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
labelTap
viewTap
```

And when tapping on the view:

```
viewTap
```

Comment: This method is for simultaneously recognizing gestures for a single view.  Since the recognizers are attached to the container and the labels, they won't conflict and won't require this method.  As far as I understand the question that is.

Comment: @Matt @Interfector I've added an example that I tried and it works. I hope it's matching your situation: A `UIGestureRecognizer` on the main `UIView` and a `UIGestureRecognizer` on a subview.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like gesture recognizers behave slightly differently from basic touch events.  Sorry for the misinformation and thank you atxe for this.  @Interfector, when you tried this, did you make sure that userInteractionEnabled was YES on the label, and that you return YES for both delegate callbacks (in case you had 2 different delegates)?  This should be a viable solution if you still want to use labels instead of buttons.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. Hopefully there's something that I've missed :)

Comment: I was under the impression that I did the same thing as you... obviously I did not :)
Thank you all for your detailed explanations.